# (Elasticsearch+IK analyzer) why I got this null_pointer_exception when I use the _analyze API?

Tags: elasticsearch

the url is

http://188.188.40.42:9200/appindex/_analyze?analyzer=ik_synonyms&text=ahaha

I got this error

```
"error": {
"root_cause": [
{
"type": "remote_transport_exception",
"reason": "[40-42][188.188.40.42:9300][indices:admin/analyze[s]]"
}
],
"type": "null_pointer_exception",
"reason": null
},
"status": 500
}
```

here is my setting

```
"settings": {
"index": {
"creation_date": "1496822869317",
"analysis": {
"filter": {
"my_synonym_filter": {
"type": "synonym",
"synonyms_path": "synonym.txt"
}
},
"analyzer": {
"ik_synonyms": {
"filter": [
"my_synonym_filter"
],
"tokenizer": "ik_smart"
}
}
}
```

I defined the ik_synonyms,why I got the null_pointer_exception when I use it?

the version of es is 2.1.1

and I found my ES never print log , here is my logging.yml

```
es.logger.level: DEBUG
rootLogger: ${es.logger.level}, console, file
logger:
  # log action execution errors for easier debugging
  action: WARN

  # deprecation logging, turn to DEBUG to see them
  deprecation: INFO, deprecation_log_file

  # reduce the logging for aws, too much is logged under the default INFO
  com.amazonaws: WARN
  # aws will try to do some sketchy JMX stuff, but its not needed.
  com.amazonaws.jmx.SdkMBeanRegistrySupport: ERROR
  com.amazonaws.metrics.AwsSdkMetrics: ERROR

  org.apache.http: ERROR

  # gateway
  #gateway: DEBUG
  #index.gateway: DEBUG

  # peer shard recovery
  #indices.recovery: DEBUG

  # discovery
  #discovery: TRACE

  index.search.slowlog: TRACE, index_search_slow_log_file
  index.indexing.slowlog: TRACE, index_indexing_slow_log_file

additivity:
  index.search.slowlog: false
  index.indexing.slowlog: false
  deprecation: false

 ...
```

Comment: What do you see in your ES logs? and which version of ES are you using?

Comment: @Val the version is 2.1.1 , and the es never print logs , I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Did you put your synonym.txt in the correct folder? It looks like ES not found your config file.

> The above configures a synonym filter, with a path of
>   analysis/synonym.txt (relative to the config location).

Source and more details: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html